# Dashcam application that saves GPS tracks alongside of video

Tags: android, gps

I am looking for a free dashcam application that I can extract GPS tracks from the saved videos (possibly using FFprobe).

Answer (score 1):

To extract GPS information from video you can use `exiftool`. If you want plaintext format you can use command:

```
exiftool -ee video.mp4 >output.txt
```

if you want to have GPX format as output you can use command:

```
exiftool -p gpx.fmt -ee video.mp4 >output.gpx
```

where `gpx.fmt` file can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/exiftool/exiftool/blob/master/fmt_files/gpx.fmt). You will need `exiftool` version 10.49 or later.

Comment: Thanks, I already tested two dashcam applications and found that the video they created doesn't have GPS tracks embedded.  Do you know any free dashcam application for Android that I can use to capture data which later I can use the above tool to extract

Comment: @mans, no idea, sorry. IMHO this will be shared in the characteristics of app